# Creating default object from empty value in php 5.4

Tags: php

i have some code like this:

```
function getAuthorizedPFComponents($pfState)
    {
        $authorizedPFComponents = new \stdClass();
                                                                                                           $compTypeMap=array('platform'=>'pfAuthorizations','mainSite'=>'mainSiteAuthorizations','microSites'=>'microSiteAuthorizations','apps'=>'appAuthorizations');
        foreach($compTypeMap as $compType=>$tagName)
        {
            $authorizationsNode=$this->pfAuthXMLDOM->getElementsByTagName($tagName)->item(0);
            foreach($authorizationsNode->getElementsByTagName('authorizations') as $pfComponentAuthElem)
            {
                foreach($pfComponentAuthElem->getElementsByTagName('allow') as $allow)
                {

                    switch($allow->getAttribute('orgCode'))
                    {
                        case 'K_ALL':
                        {
                            $authorizedPFComponents->$compType->{$pfComponentAuthElem->getAttribute('pfComponentCode')}->storeCode=$allow->getAttribute('storeCode');
                           }

                        }
```

It shows a warning:

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value
```

The warning is traced back to the code under `case K_ALL:`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is missing some details, such as where does the error come from?

Comment: it is showing error on last line  i.e.,    $authorizedPFComponents->$compType->{$pfComponentAuthElem->getAttribute('pfComponentCode')}->storeCode=$allow->getAttribute('storeCode')                                             It says that trying to create default object from empty valu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was too long for a mere comment, so I'll remove it when it has outlived its usefulness.

First thing you should do is make the code simpler; there's a lot of stuff going on in that one statement:

```
$compCode = $pfComponentAuthElem->getAttribute('pfComponentCode');
$storeCode = $allow->getAttribute('storeCode');
```

And add debug code:

```
var_dump($authorizedPFComponents->$compType);
var_dump($authorizedPFComponents->$compType->$compCode);

$authorizedPFComponents->$compType->$compCode->storeCode = $storeCode;
```

---

Consider this code:

```
$x->y = 'test';
```

If `$x` is not defined, it will issue a warning:

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in xxx
```

The same goes for your chain of references:

```
$authorizedPFComponents->$compType->$compCode->storeCode
```

If any of those paths is empty, the next `->yyy` will cause that warning.

Comment: Did as u said but...how to fix it if any empty as u said in the chain of references??

Comment: I can't answer that for you, because it's highly specific to your logic. Perhaps you could create an `stdClass` every time you encounter an empty chain in the path?

Comment: yeah u said is rit...at every reference point i need to create stdClass..it resolved thanks...my changed code is...       case 'K_ALL':
      {
       if(!isset($authorizedPFComponents->$compType))$authorizedPFComponents->$compType = new \stdClass();
       if(!isset($authorizedPFComponents->$compType->$compCode))$authorizedPFComponents->$compType->$compCode = new \stdClass();
          $authorizedPFComponents->$compType->$compCode->storeCode=$storeCode;